# Placing items in a grid layout with arbitrary width, but defined span

Tags: html, css, flexbox, calendar, css-grid

I'm having difficulty finding the right technology/technique to display my layout. See picture:

[Desired layout picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV5AK.png)

This layout is similar to a calendar.  An example cell is denoted in blue. The challenging part for me is a cell may have a child element that should span multiple cells/columns. The width of the calendar is full width, so each cell is of dynamic width.

I was originally using an HTML table but found that to be inflexible, so I have started using CSS Grid. With CSS Grid I still don't appear to be able to accomplish the desired layout. It looks like only direct child elements of the grid-container can be placed into the grid (in my case, these are cells). I desire the child elements of the cells to also be placed throughout the grid. This appears somewhat supported using "display: contents", but this is not support on all browsers, such as IE and Edge. I also see mention of CSS subgrid specification, but that doesn't appear to be available/supported yet.

Are there any other layout techniques or strategies which should allow for my desired layout design?

Edit: Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sy70c2j6/1683. I'd like some sort of styling to be able to specify that span2 and span3 span across 2 or 3 cells respectively.

```
// This doesn't accomplish it, but I desire something like this
.span2 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Comment: Could you share what you tried?

Comment: Sure - It's something along the lines of this: https://jsfiddle.net/sy70c2j6/1683/. The issue is that I can't seem to specify any styling for span2 or span3 to get the item to span 2 and 3 cells respectively

Answer (score 0):

You could kinda do this with grid-layout. You could create rows and for each row draw a line with `:after` pseudo-element. And you could also create columns with `absolute` positioned elements. Then in each row you can create cells that can span on multiple columns.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-column: span 7;
  position: relative;
}

.cols {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  z-index: -1;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.cols > div {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: span;
}

.row:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid #8EBA75;
  background: #D5E7D3;
  padding: 20px;
}

.row-1 {grid-row: 1}
.row-2 {grid-row: 2}
.row-3 {grid-row: 3}


.col-1-4 {grid-column: 1 / 4;}
.col-1-2 {grid-column: 1 / 2;}
.col-3-4 {grid-column: 3 / 4}
.col-5-7 {grid-column: 5 / 7}
.col-3-5 {grid-column: 3 / 5}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell col-1-4 row-1"></div>
    <div class="cell col-1-2 row-2"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell col-3-4 row-1"></div>
    <div class="cell col-5-7 row-1"></div>
    <div class="cell col-3-4 row-2"></div>
    <div class="cell col-3-5 row-3"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cols">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```